# Extract Data from Kafka topic (Version 0.9)

Tags: apache-kafka

I am in trouble with Kafka 0.9 version. I want to retrieve data form a topic starting    at specific **offset**.

Can anyone help me?

I've tried a lot of commands for do that but i cannot reach the result. With this command i can read all the messages
`/products/software/Apache/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic <topic_name> --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --from-beginning --property print.key=true --property key.separator="-"`

If i try to add props `--offset` and `--partition` i've this error in console `'offset' is not a recognized option`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual commands you've tried with --offset and --partition ?

Comment: `/products/software/Apache/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic topicsvilnfctr --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --property print.key=true --property key.separator="-" --partitions 0 --offset 1886484`

Answer (score 0):

You can download a later version of the Kafka CLI tools that do support these arguments.

In general, you should also upgrade Kafka itself for many, many security patches, including Log4Shell.